# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an app which post stories in a carousel that holds videos and images. If a post is a video it has a sound on/off icon like Instagram. When I go from the first video to second or third video and click on the sound on/off icon then my app crashes.

Below is the code snippet :

```
ArrayList<String> b_checkSound = new ArrayList<>();
cell_soundoff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.setVolume(1, 1);
                cell_soundon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                cell_soundoff.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                if(b_checkSound != null) {
                    b_checkSound.add(position, "true");
                }
            }
        }
    }
});

cell_soundon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.setVolume(0, 0);
                cell_soundoff.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                cell_soundon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                if (b_checkSound != null && b_checkSound.size() > position) {
                    b_checkSound.remove(position);
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

This is the error i get:

```
08-27 16:27:28.954 27154-27154/com.leadplatform.kfarmers E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.leadplatform.kfarmers, PID: 27154
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:483)
        at com.leadplatform.kfarmers.view.diary.DiaryListFragment$Stroy_imageviewAdapter$1.onClick(DiaryListFragment.java:2887)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6891)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26083)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a HashMap in this case, because the size of array is not fixed in your case, and using this you will not get worry about `IndexOutOfBoundsException` exception :

```
        HashMap<Integer, String> b_checkSound = new HashMap<>(); //CHANGE HERE map with pos->value  
        cell_soundoff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                        mediaPlayer.setVolume(1, 1);
                        cell_soundon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        cell_soundoff.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        if(b_checkSound != null) {
                            b_checkSound.put(position, "true"); //CHANGE HERE
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
//
        cell_soundon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                        mediaPlayer.setVolume(0, 0);
                        cell_soundoff.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        cell_soundon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        if (b_checkSound != null) {//CHANGE HERE
                            b_checkSound.remove(position);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like your array is empty and you‘re trying to add an element after the first element using position = 1.

Comment: Correct. The add command has no check for the size of the List. So you try to add after the end of the list (not at the end).
``if position >= list.size() list.add("true") else list.add(position,"true")`` - something like that

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use an ArrayList for this type of problem, because you depend on position, but you can't add something on second index in an empty array!

Try using a HashMap instead, or if you really like optimization and performance, you can go for bit flags and bit masks.

EDIT: I proposed this because I believe you want to keep track of each individual item in the adapter being muted or no.

Answer (score 0):

This variable `position` is initialized elsewhere and I don't know how you use it and modify it.  
You should know that indexes in lists are **zero based**.  
So for the 1st item position is 0.  
If you did not consider this fact, then you could get this type of error.

Answer (score -1):

As you insert the true in b_checkSound

```
if(b_checkSound != null) {
b_checkSound.add(position, "true");
}
```

But your b_checkSound has zero size so add one more check:

```
if(b_checkSound != null) {
   if(b_checkSound.size()==0){
      b_checkSound.add("true");
   }else{
        b_checkSound.add(position, "true");
   }
}
```